# order email address file by last name in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, sorting

I have a file that is listed line by line as such:

```
first.last@example.com
first.last@example.com
last@example.com...
```

Note that some of the addresses don't have a first name, in which case, it is just the last name.

How can I write a simple Ruby script to read in this file (call it `email.txt`)
and write it back to the file in sorted order by last name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in a file, e.g. `sort_by_last.rb`:

```
puts IO.readlines('email.txt').sort_by { |e| e.match(/[^\.]+(?=@)/)[0].downcase }
```

then run it:

```
ruby sort_by_last.rb > emails_sorted.txt
```

---

#### For variable filename

Set contents of `sort_by_last.rb` to

```
puts STDIN.readlines.sort_by { |e| e.match(/[^\.]+(?=@)/)[0].downcase }
```

then run:

```
ruby sort_by_last.rb < email.txt > emails_sorted.txt
```